# My servlets are giving 404 and 500 error, they wont show up, only one shows up

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

Update. I removed the constructor with the EmployeeService and object mapper, and the errors were resolved. Was the problem caused because i had the @WebServlet as well as the contextloaderlistener? i had the impression that i needed both.

This is the only servlet that functions correctly, it is not linked to my contextloaderlistener at all.

```
@WebServlet(value = "/register")
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {

private final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
    logger.info("Register Servlet Running");
    resp.getWriter().write("<head><title>Save The Date</title></head>" + "");
    resp.getWriter().write(" <img src='./images/savethedate.png' alt='logos'/>" + "");
    resp.getWriter().write("<h2>Wedding Registration</h2>");

    resp.getWriter().write("<ul>" + "<li>    "
            + "<form method='post><label for'bname'>Please enter Bride's Name:</label><input type='text' id='bname'  name='bname'/></li>"
            + "<li> "
            + "<label for'gname'>Please enter Groom's Name:</label><input type='text' id='gname'  name='gname'/></li>"

            // Venue selection

            + "<li><p>Please choose a venue  <select name ='venue'> <option value='Hamptons Getaway'>Hampton's Getaway</option></p>"
            + "<option value='St. Mark's Cathedral'>St. Mark's Cathedral</option>"
            + "<option value='French Man's Cove'>French Man's Cove</option>"
            + "<option value='Blue Lagoon'>Blue Lagoon</option></select></li>"
            + "<li><p>Please choose a date </span><input type='date' name='date' id='date' '/>"
            // Number of guests
            + "<li><label for'guests'>How many Guests ?</label><input type='number' id='guests' guests='guests'/></li></ul>"
            + "<h2> Available for Hire </h2>" + "<div id='hire'>"

            + "<ul><li><span> Do you need a Florist ? </span><input type='radio' name='fl_response' id='Yes' value='Yes'/><label for 'Yes'>Yes</label>"
            + "<input type='radio' name='fl_response' id='No' value='No'/><label for 'No'>No</label></li>"

            + "<li><span> Do you need Musicians ? </span><input type='radio' name='M_response' id='Yes' value='Yes'/><label for 'Yes'>Yes</label>"
            + "<input type='radio' name='M_response' id='No' value='No'/><label for 'No'>No</label></li>"

            + "<li><span> Do you need Caterers ? </span><input type='radio' name='C_response' id='Yes' value='Yes'/><label for 'Yes'>Yes</label>"
            + "<input type='radio' name='C_response' id='No' value='No'/><label for 'No'>No</label></li>"

            + "<li><span> Do you need Photographers ? </span><input type='radio' name='P_response' id='Yes' value='Yes'/><label for 'Yes'>Yes</label>"
            + "<input type='radio' name='P_response' id='No' value='No'/><label for 'No'>No</label></li>" + "</div>"

            + "<div class='submit'><input type='submit' value='Register' id='submit'/></div>" + "</form>");

    resp.getWriter()
            .write("<select name='Food'> " + "<option value ='Fish'>Fish</option>"
                    + "<option value = 'Meat'>Meat</option>" + "<option value ='Vegetarian'>Vegetarian</option>"
                    + "</select>" + ""
                    // css below
                    + "<style type=text/css>" + "*{ font-family: Arial,Verdana, sans-serif;" + "color: #665544;}"
                    + "#hire, li{border-bottom:1px solid #efefef;margin:10px;padding-bottom:10px;width: 400px;}"
                    + "h1{background-color:#efefef;margin-top: 20px;padding:10px 0px 5px 0px;width: 400px;}"
                    + "img.align-center {display:block;margin:0px auto;}" + "</style>" + "");
}
```

}

However, my 5 other servlets wont show up, i get a mixture of errors when i trouble shoot. 400, 404, 500. I tried removing the @webservlet annotation and relying on the mapping in the contextloader listening and i still get 404 error. I do not use the xml for context mapping, nut i will include it anyway.
my xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>Hello, Servlets!</display-name>
    
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.revature.save_the_date.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

this is what i have for my contextloaderlistener. I commented out the employee stuff, i was troubleshooting by removing it and using only the @WebServlet annotation inside the employee servlet. However it gave me the same error 404.

```
public class ContextLoaderListener implements ServletContextListener
{
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        logger.info("Initializing Application.....");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        WeddingDAO weddingDAO = new WeddingDAO();
        WeddingService weddingService = new WeddingService(weddingDAO);
        WeddingServlet weddingServlet = new WeddingServlet(weddingService, mapper);

        RegistryDAO registryDAO = new RegistryDAO();
        RegistryService registryService = new RegistryService(registryDAO);
        RegistryServlet registryServlet = new RegistryServlet(registryService, mapper);

        /*
         * EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO(); EmployeeService employeeService
         * = new EmployeeService(employeeDAO); EmployeeServlet employeeServlet = new
         * EmployeeServlet(employeeService,mapper);
         */

        VenueDAO venueDAO = new VenueDAO();
        VenueService venueService = new VenueService(venueDAO);
        VenueServlet venueServlet = new VenueServlet(venueService, mapper);

        GuestDAO guestDAO = new GuestDAO();
        GuestService guestService = new GuestService(guestDAO);
        GuestServlet guestServlet = new GuestServlet(guestService, mapper);

        FoodDAO foodDAO = new FoodDAO();
        FoodService foodService = new FoodService(foodDAO);
        FoodServlet foodServlet = new FoodServlet(foodService, mapper);

        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();

        context.addServlet("WeddingServlet", weddingServlet).addMapping("/wedding/*");
        context.addServlet("RegistryServlet", registryServlet).addMapping("/registry/*");
        context.addServlet("FoodServlet", foodServlet).addMapping("/food/*");
        context.addServlet("GuestServlet", guestServlet).addMapping("/guest/*");
        //context.addServlet("EmployeeServlet",employeeServlet).addMapping("/employee/*");
        context.addServlet("VenueService", venueServlet).addMapping("/venue/*");

        logger.info("Application initialized@");
    }

    @Override public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ServletContextListener.super.contextDestroyed(sce);
    }

}
```

here is the employee servlet, does the @WebServlet annotation causes a conflict with the mapping inside the contextloaderlistener, I removed it and tried and i get error 500 then when i refresh the page it goes back to error 400.

```
@WebServlet(value = "/employee") 
public class EmployeeServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private final EmployeeService employeeService;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public EmployeeServlet(EmployeeService employeeService, ObjectMapper mapper)
    {
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        resp.getWriter().write("<head><title>Save The Date !</title></head>" + "<div id=top>" + "<h1>Save The Date !</h1>" + "<img src='./images/savethedate.png' alt='logos'/>"
                + "<h3>You are loggen in as: Tom Nash " + "" + "" + "<h3> Your Schedule</h3>" + "<ul>" + "<li> Frenchman's Cove Feb. 17, 2023</li>" + "<li> Blue Lagoon Feb. 28, 2023</li>" + "</ul>"
                + "<button type ='button' class='collapsible'>Add Venue</button>"// venu
                + "     <div class='content'>" + "<form method='post'>" + "<label for'venue'>Name of venue:</label><input type='text' id='venue'  name='venue'/>"
                + "<label for'location'>Location:</label><input type='text' id='location'  name='location'/>"
                + "<label for'Capacity'>Capacity:</label><input type='text' id='capacity'  name='capacity'/>" + "<label for'phone'>Phone no.:</label><input type='number' id='phone'  name='phone'/>"
                + "</form>" + "     </div>"

                + "<button type ='button' class='collapsible'>Add Caterer</button>"// caterer
                + "     <div class='content'>" + "<form method='post'>" + "<label for'caterer'>Name of Caterer:</label><input type='text' id='caterer'  name='caterer'/>"
                + "<label for'cousine'>Cousine:</label><input type='text' id='cousine'  name='cousine'/>" + "<label for'phone'>Phone:</label><input type='number' id='phone'  name='phone'/>"
                + "</form>" + "     </div>" + "<button type ='button' class='collapsible'>Add Florist</button>"// florist
                + "     <div class='content'>" + "<form method='post'>" + "<label for'florist'>Name of Florist:</label><input type='text' id='florist'  name='florist'/>"
                + "<label for'phone'>Phone:</label><input type='number' id='phone'  name='phone'/>" + "</form>" + "     </div>"
                + "<button type ='button' class='collapsible'>Add Photographer</button>"// photographers
                + "     <div class='content'>" + "<form method='post'>" + "<label for'caterer'>Name of Photographer:</label><input type='text' id='photographer'  name='photographer'/>"
                + "<label for'phone'>Phone:</label><input type='number' id='phone'  name='phone'/>" + "</form>" + "     </div>" + "<button type ='button' class='collapsible'>Add Musician</button>"
                // musicians
                + "     <div class='content'>" + "<form method='post'>" + "<label for'musician'>Name of Musician:</label><input type='text' id='musician'  name='musician'/>"
                + "<label for'Style'>Cousine:</label><input type='text' id='style'  name='style'/>" + "<label for'phone'>Phone:</label><input type='number' id='phone'  name='phone'/>" + "</form>"
                + "     </div>"

                + "" + "</div>"

                + ""// CSS
                + "<style type=text/css>" + "h1{background-color:DarkCyan;text-align:center;}" + "#top {width:400px;}" + "img {margin:10px;}" + ".collapsible {background-color: #eee;" + "color: #444;"
                + "  cursor: pointer;" + "  padding: 18px;" + " " + "  width: 100%;" + "  border: none;" + "  text-align: left;" + "  outline: none;" + "  font-size: 15px;}"
                + ".active, .collapsible:hover {" + "  background-color: #ccc;" + "}" + ".content {" + "  padding: 0 18px;" + "  display: none;" + "  overflow: hidden;"
                + "  background-color: #f1f1f1;" + "}"

                // js
                + "<script>" + "var coll = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible');" + "var i;" + "for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {" + "  coll[i].addEventListener('click', function() {"
                + "    this.classList.toggle('active');" + "    var content = this.nextElementSibling;" + "    if (content.style.display) {" + "      content.style.display = 'none';" + "    } else {"
                + "      content.style.display = 'block' ;" + "    }" + "  });" + "}" + "</script>" + "");
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try using @Override annotation on doGet and doPost on your not-working servlets. In your employee servlet, I can see, you have not overridden them.

Comment: i did that then got error 500, then 404

Comment: @lams if it's not an actual override, that adding that annotation would break the build. code that doesn't compile won't return a status

Comment: You are throwing 500 already on POST over Employee servlet. What is the value for wasRegistered flag?

Comment: there is no value there, i am not using that method at all, i just want the page to show up. even without the doPost method i get the same errors. I trouble shoot by removing the doPost method and same 500 and 404 error

Comment: Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. this is what i get, even when i remove doPost

Comment: @lams I'm not using that method at all? What do you think this is? boolean wasRegistered = employeeService.addEmployee(newEmployee);
            if (wasRegistered)

Comment: sorry, i mean it is not being called, I am not calling the doPost method, i removed it from the servlet, i'll update the code here

Comment: ok, major update, i removed the constructor with the employee service and mapper and it actually worked, i am not sure why it worked

Comment: Maybe you would like to go ahead and answer your question for community members.